# How to I add up a series of cells containing values in the "day, hrs, mins"

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

The cells I need to total contain values in the "day, hrs, mins" format so they don't just added up like simple numbers. I need the total number of days, hrs, mins.

The Cells contain values calculated using

```
=INT(cell-cell)&" days "&TEXT(cell-cell,"h"" hrs ""m"" mins """)?
```

What should I do?

Here's a screenshot:
[image]
It's the bright yellow cells I am trying to figure out the forumal for. Many thanks

Comment: Dates & times are numbers, don't convert them to strings, format the cells so they display how you want (something like `d " days " h " hrs " m " mins"`), then adding them is trivial. What cells are you substracting to get these dates & times?

Comment: For "Time in Transit" I calculated the difference between "Departure Time" and Arrival Time" on the same row.
For "Layover Duration" I calculated the different between the "Arrival Time" and the next "Departure Time".

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is minute the smallest unit of time?  You can sum days, hours and mins separately and sum those three using the corresponding fractions.  Use cell formatting to change output from decimal to time display.
1 hour = 1/24
1 minute = 1/1440
If Time In Transit column structure is fixed you can use column by example to extract just the numbers, then do the math.